# Linq2db scaffolding and association naming

Tags: c#, linq2db

I've tried to scaffold an existing database using the t4 file as described [here](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/tree/master/Source/LinqToDB.Templates)

Now I've found that the relation I've have really ugly looking naming,consider this case

```
/// <summary>
    /// FK_XX_CONVENZIONI_XX_COMPAGNIE_BackReference
    /// </summary>
    [Association(ThisKey="IdCompagnia", OtherKey="IdCompagnia", CanBeNull=true, Relationship=Relationship.OneToMany, IsBackReference=true)]
    public IEnumerable<BenefitConvenzioni> XXCONVENZIONIXXCOMPAGNIEs { get; set; }
```

I've tried as suggested to put

```
 GetSchemaOptions.GetAssociationMemberName = key => "Association_" + key.MemberName;
```

But it doesn't change the behavior... any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put this code **before** `LoadMetadata`

```
GetSchemaOptions.GetAssociationMemberName = key => "Association_" + key.MemberName; 

// other tweaks

LoadMetadata(....)
```

It is also mentioned in documentation [Configuring generation process](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db/tree/master/Source/LinqToDB.Templates#configuring-generation-process)

Comment: ok, but is there a way I can tell to leave the references as ```FK_XX_CONVENZIONI_XX_COMPAGNIE_BackReference``` and not ```XXCONVENZIONIXXCOMPAGNIEs ```

Comment: Currently there is no way to setup option for that but you can override function `ConvertToCompilable`:

`ConvertToCompilable = (name, removeUnderscores) => ConvertToCompilableDefault(name, name.StartsWith("FK_") ?  false : removeUnderscores);`